# Expected expression before , token

Tags: c, windows, draw

My code:

```
DrawText (hdc, TEXT ("PPPPPPP"), -1, &, DT_SINGLELINE|DT_CENTER|DT_VCENT);
```

Compiler gives me this erorr:

```
[Error] expected expression before ',' token
```

Thanks.

Comment: what the heck does `&,` mean?

Comment: @RaymondChen: "Take address of, oh, nevermind."

Comment: possible duplicate of [Expected identifier or something?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20809447/expected-identifier-or-something)

Comment: This is like asking why your algebraic calculator doesn't accept the input `4 + `.

Comment: Also, `DT_VCENT` should be `DT_VCENTER`.

Answer (score 2):

That lonely `&` is the error, that's not correct syntax: the unary address-of operator `&` needs something to take the address of, and you're not providing an argument to the operator.

From [this documentation page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162498%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), the fourth argument to `DrawText()` is a pointer to a [`RECT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162897%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) structure which you seem to be missing.

Without seeing more of your code, it's hard to know what your particular `RECT` instance is called.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20809447/expected-identifier-or-something?noredirect=1#comment31200431_20809447

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are using unary `&` operator without its operand. You need an operand (which must be an l-value) for `&` operator otherwise its a compilation error. If you declare the `RECT` structure then fourth argument is a pointer to `RECT`, like `&rect`;

```
 RECT rect;
 ...
 DrawText (hdc, TEXT("PPPPPPP"), -1, &rect, DT_SINGLELINE|DT_CENTER|DT_VCENT);
```

Comment: With this I get error:  [Error] lvalue required as unary '&' operand

Comment: @Janac; There was typo. Fixed that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20809447/expected-identifier-or-something?noredirect=1#comment31200431_20809447

Comment: What does that mean? That's a different issue what [chris](http://stackoverflow.com/users/962089/chris) stated in his comment.

Comment: @Janac Learn to use something called debugger

Comment: @haccks he's asking you to anser his other question

Comment: @rullof; lol. That is already answered. :)

Comment: @haccks he didn't understood it yet

Comment: Can i just delet this & ???

Comment: You have to pass five arguments to your function. After deleting that you should pass an argument expected by your function (like `&rect`). Read this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1974035/2455888) also.